# Vagrant user permissions

Tags: permissions, users, chown, vagrant

What I like about vagrant is that all the permissions work out of the box when provisioned with Puppet. However I can't get the same permissions to work on my digitalocean droplet.

On my vagrant box, as the user `vagrant`, I can `cd` to a folder with owner: `www-data:www-data`. Any operations I do there are carried out, what seems, as the user `www-data` even though I am `vagrant`. How is this possible? For example: `touch file.txt` creates a file with owner `www-data:www-data`. I want to be able to get this to work but I don't know how.

Comment: what does `pwd` command return? Can you run `su vagrant`?

Comment: @nssnd pwd returns the current working directory, in my case, `var/www/test`. I can also `su vagrant` but it asks me for a password which I don't have since I'm using ssh keys

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to do `cd ~` before `pwd`. As I remember, default password for vagrant user is `vagrant` - you can try that. Also, try to go root `sudo -i` and then `su vagrant` if password doesn't match.

Comment: What is the output of `env`?